# Artifactory archive search in parts of repo?

Tags: artifactory

I have a artifactory server with alot of content and alot of .zip-files. Artifactory supports archive search which allows you to search for specific files within the archives.

The problem is that when using the API you can only specify file name (or keyword) and repo. The problem is that the repo contains so much files that the maximum number of hits is reached. It's also not that efficient to search everything every time when I know the path to the interesting 10%.

Does anyone know if it's possible to search part of the repo using the API? Do I have to create virtual repos that points to a subset of the repo?

Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and most efficient way to search and filter inside archive entries is using the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI). With that, you can specify your search pattern and filter out unwanted results.

```sh
jfrog rt s <repository name>/<repository path> --archive-entries=<path-in-archive>
```

Example:

```sh
jfrog rt s generic-local/food/* --archive-entries=cheese/milk.txt
# Results: pizza.zip
```

You can also use [File Specs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UsingFileSpecs) for more complex queries:

Create filespec.json:

```json
{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "generic-local/food/*",
      "archiveEntries": "cheese/milk",
      "exclusions": "*lasagne*"
    },
    {
      "pattern": "thor/*",
      "archiveEntries": "hammer"
    }
  ]
}
```

Run the following:

```sh
jfrog rt s --spec=filespec.json
# Possible results: pizza.zip and weapon.zip
```

Notice: To use archive search, make sure "Archive Search Enabled" is checked under `Administration` | `Artifactory` | `General Settings`.

Read more:

1. [Searching files](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-SearchingFiles) using the JFrog CLI.
2. More about [File Specs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+File+Specs).

Comment: Aha! I was only looking at the API methods, totally missed the CLI. That should probably do it. Thanks!

Comment: Question related to CLI. Is it possible to call the restAPI with CLI commands? I don't want to install the CLI on the machine, I would prefer to just curl the host. It's part of some automation scripts which is performed through python at this point.

Comment: No. The CLI "wrap" the REST API. Installation of the CLI is very easy:
"curl -fL https://getcli.jfrog.io | sh && ./jfrog c add jona --interactive=false --artifactory-url=<artifactory-url> --user=<username> --password=<password>" and then run "./jfrog rt s"

Comment: Mkay, too bad I can't access the full functionality of the restAPI if the CLI wraps it. But it is what it is I guess. We have all the other API functions as module in a python library so it would add an extra dimension to implement the CLI. But I'll probably find a way to do it :). Thanks again!

Comment: Hmmm just to be clear - you can run "jfrog rt curl" commands to execute REST API calls. One thing you can't do is sending CLI commands to the REST API.