# Search for a file in a ZIP file using JFROG CLI

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I saw there's a way to search for files using JFROG CLI:
https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-cli/searching-files

But is there a way to search for files inside a ZIP file? I saw there's an option with `--archive-entries`:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68033621/2653179

But it didn't work and also seems like it's searching for ZIP files containing a certain file. I'd like to search for a certain file in a specific ZIP file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `--include` in `jf search` as you can see in documentation.

Comment: Seems like `--include` is for getting specific fields from the search results, not searching for a file in a ZIP file. See: https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-cli/example-3?tocId=uLr9~gn4Zz65XRfuUV97uQ